# Pygame only shows the middle of the picture

Tags: python, pygame

I'm coding something with PyGame and it should show a map but it only shows the middle of the map.
There are no errors except that it doesn't show the whole map.

This is my code:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

#Show map
image = pygame.image.load("map.jpg")

#Game window
width, height = image.get_size()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("show picture")

#Program
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    window.blit(image, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This is what I get:
[image]

and I don't even see the white part. This is what the map is supposed to look like:

[image: Working code]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This code works on my machine as expected, using python 3.9 and pygame 2.1.2 on a windows machine. What are your versions / system?

Comment: Tested on ubuntu 22.04 and it works fine. Check your environment for anything that may interfere - especially path for the image and the image itself.

Comment: @ChristianKarcher i have python 3.12 and pygame 2.5.2 and i use windows

Comment: Just tested this combination, works as well. Try @mlokos suggestions, is the image ok? Do other images work? Is it connected to the size of the image? Try smaller ones, see if you can identify potential causes.

Comment: @ChristianKarcher there shouldn't be a problem with the image size bc my screen is bigger (image = 2800, 1354, screen = 2880, 1920) I'll try to scale the picture down

Comment: @ChristianKarcher scaling worked!!